# Return a Name corrosponding to its ID from JSON object Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have an array of JSON objects for example

```
"data": {
    "id": 20,
    "name" : "Car"
},
"data": {
    "id": 2,
    "name" : "Bus"
},
"data": {
    "id": 30,
    "name" : "Bike"
}
```

I am getting these values from database and storing them in a shared preference

```
SharedPreferences vehicleData = getSharedPreferences("vehicleData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor vehicleEditor = vehicleData.edit();

                    vID.append(vt.get(i).getId()).append(",");
                    vName.append(vt.get(i).getTypeName()).append(",");
```

I have a spinner in my android app where I am showing the values as "Car", "Bus", "Bike" etc (from the shared preference).

```
SharedPreferences vehicleData = getSharedPreferences("vehicleData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String ids = vehicleData.getString("vehicle_type_id", "");
    final String names = vehicleData.getString(ids, "");

    String[] singleName = names.split(",");
    String[] singleID = ids.split(",");

    typeSpinner = findViewById(R.id.vehicle_type_spinner);

    ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < singleName.length; i++) {
        namelist.add(singleID[i].concat(" ".concat(singleName[i])));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namelist);
    typeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and getting the spinner value in this way

```
String typeName = String.valueOf(typeSpinner.getSelectedItem());
```

What I want to do is when a user selects a value from the spinner (Ex: Car), I want to store the ID of that value i.e 1 in a variable.

I guess this is a very basic question but I cannot solve it. How can I do this?

Comment: What is your current code looks like?

Comment: Currently its a mess. What I do is first I get a string of both name and id in a comma separated string ("Car, Bus, Bike" and "1, 2, 3"), then I split each of them at comma, and run a for loop through and form a concatenated string something like "1 Car". In doing to i get the spinner values as the same "1 Car".  
Then i again separate them to get the ID when a snipper is selected. Like I said its a mess.

Comment: You have the json values as serialized java object right? So you can search on that list object which has the name equals to selected value as I understand. Am I missing something?

Comment: actually I am getting these values from database and storing them in shared preference in another activity as a key value pair ("id", 1) and ("name", car). Something like this. i will edit my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this piece of code can help you :

```
private void initSpinner() {
        List<Data> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfData.add(new Data(1,"Car"));
    listOfData.add(new Data(2,"Bus"));
    listOfData.add(new Data(3,"Bike"));  

        List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (Data data : listOfData) {  
         listOfNames.add(data.getName()); 
        }

        spinner.setItems(listOfNames); 
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() { 
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
                   long selectedDataId = listOfData.get(position);
                   String selectedDataName = listOfNames.get(position); 
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to get the position of each value. I have tried this way, but its not full prove in my case as by id can be different than its position. check my edited question for better understanding.

Comment: No , i just create tow type of lists , first list for class data and the seconde is for names , when you click in choosen name you get the position of this name and you passe it into list of class to get the id of this name

Comment: oh. I see. let me try this.

Comment: So the idea is to get the position of the id in the id array. and get the name at that position in the name array.

Comment: yes , that's i want to explain , you put the string array of names into the spinner after that when you click in the item you get the position of this name and you use it the get the id from other the array .

Comment: Thanks. it solved my problem. I marked your answer correct.